# Download image from QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, rapidjson

I saw an other thread talking about this, but I'm not succeeding in the display of my image.

Currently, I'm downloading my image like this :

```
void MyClass::imgHandle() {
QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  QUrl url(_code.c_str());
  QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

  QEventLoop eventLoop;

  connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),&eventLoop,SLOT(quit()));
  eventLoop.exec();

  if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
      QImageReader imageReader(reply);
      imageReader.setAutoDetectImageFormat (false);
      _img = imageReader.read();
    }

}
```

_code is built from a code got from a Json parsing, and the url looks like this : `http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/33.gif`
_img is a QImage in my class.

And in my other class I do this :

```
int OtherClass::displayWeather()
{
 MyClass mC = new MyClass;

  mC->exec() // Where I get the code from the Json


  QLabel *imgWeather = new QLabel(this);                                              

  imgWeather->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(mC->getImg())); 
  // getImg() return a QImage. 
  //The QImage created in MyClass.

  imgWeather->setGeometry(1700, 0, 120, 120);
}
```

And at the end .. Nothing is displayed !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the `QImageReader::read` result:

```
QImageReader imageReader(reply);
imageReader.setAutoDetectImageFormat(false);
QImage _img = imageReader.read();
if (_img.isNull())
{
    qDebug() << imageReader.errorString();
}
```

In your case the error is *"Unsupported image format"*. 
By default `QImageReader` tries to autodetect the image format and you've just disabled it by calling `setAutoDetectImageFormat(false)`. Remove it and `QImageReader` will do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly ! I copy.pasted the code without checking what it does ..